# Add rows for skipped stages in a process

Tags: r, dataframe, analytics

I am looking to take a data frame in R and augment it based on what I see in two of the columns, V1 and V2. In short, I have stages S1-S6 which are strings.

For every row where there is a gap in the stage, I need to add rows. Looking at the data frames below, if I saw 'S 3' and 'S 3' in the same row, I would not need to do anything. Similarly, if I saw 'S 3' and 'S 4' in the same row, I would not need to do anything either.

### Example 1

Input:

```
----------------------------------
|Var1               | V1   | V2  |    
----------------------------------
|0060a00000fUbAnAAK |'S 2' |'S 5'|
----------------------------------
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------
|Var1               | V1   | V2  |    
----------------------------------
|0060a00000fUbAnAAK |'S 2' |'S 3'|
----------------------------------
|0060a00000fUbAnAAK |'S 3' |'S 4'|
----------------------------------
|0060a00000fUbAnAAK |'S 4' |'S 5'|
----------------------------------
```

### Example 2

Input:

```
----------------------------------
|Var1               | V1   | V2  |    
----------------------------------
|0060a00000fUbAnAAK |'S 5' |'S 3'|
----------------------------------
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------
|Var1               | V1   | V2  |    
----------------------------------
|0060a00000fUbAnAAK |'S 5' |'S 4'|
----------------------------------
|0060a00000fUbAnAAK |'S 4' |'S 3'|
----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea using `tidyverse` is to convert to long format, separate the numbers from `S` and complete the sequence. Once we have that, we paste the columns back together (`S` and `values`) and convert back to wide format. Finally, we take the lagged variable of `V1`, and remove `NA`s, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 gather(var, val, -1) %>% 
 separate(val, into = c('char', 'number'), sep = ' ') %>% 
 mutate(number = as.numeric(number)) %>% 
 complete(nesting(var, Var1, char), number = full_seq(min(number):max(number), 1)) %>%
 unite('V1_2', c('char', 'number'), sep = ' ') %>% 
 group_by(var) %>% 
 mutate(new = row_number()) %>% 
 spread(var, V1_2) %>% 
 mutate(V1 = lag(V1)) %>% 
 na.omit() %>% 
 select(-new)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>    Var1  V1    V2   
>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
> 1 xxx   S 2   S 3  
> 2 xxx   S 3   S 4  
> 3 xxx   S 4   S 5
> ```

Answer (score 0):

## updated answer

This update also take decreasing stages into account

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("Var1               | V1   | V2
  0060a00000fUbAnAAK |S 2 |S 5
  0060a00000fUbAnAAK_ |S 5 |S 3")

#                   Var1  V1  V2
# 1:  0060a00000fUbAnAAK S 2 S 5
# 2: 0060a00000fUbAnAAK_ S 5 S 3
```

**code**

```
#determine order of stages
DT[ as.numeric( gsub("[^0-9]", "", V2 ) ) < as.numeric( gsub("[^0-9]", "", V1 ) ), order := "desc" ]
DT[ is.na( order) , order := "asc" ]
#melt DT to long format
DT <- melt( DT, id.vars = c("Var1","order"), value.name = "stage")
#get stage as numeric and clean up unwanted columns
DT[, `:=`(stage = as.numeric( gsub("[^0-9]", "", stage)))]
#create new stages based on minimum and maximum stage per Var1-value
#use different methodes of ascending and descneding stages, then bind the rows together
rbind(
  DT[order == "asc", .( V1 = paste0( "S ", min(stage): (max(stage) - 1 ) ), 
                        V2 = paste0( "S ", (min(stage)+1):max(stage) ) ), by = .(Var1)],
  DT[order == "desc", .( V1 = paste0( "S ", max(stage): (min(stage) + 1 ) ), 
                         V2 = paste0( "S ", (max(stage)-1):min(stage) ) ), by = .(Var1)]
)
```

**output**

```
#                   Var1  V1  V2
# 1:  0060a00000fUbAnAAK S 2 S 3
# 2:  0060a00000fUbAnAAK S 3 S 4
# 3:  0060a00000fUbAnAAK S 4 S 5
# 4: 0060a00000fUbAnAAK_ S 5 S 4
# 5: 0060a00000fUbAnAAK_ S 4 S 3
```

## previous answer

```
`data.table` solution

**sample data**

    library(data.table)
    DT <- fread("Var1               | V1   | V2
      0060a00000fUbAnAAK |S 2 |S 5")

**code**

    #melt DT to long format
    DT <- melt( DT, id.vars = "Var1", value.name = "stage")
    #get stage as numeric and clean up unwanted columns
    DT[, `:=`(variable = NULL, stage = as.numeric( gsub("[^0-9]", "", stage)))]
    #create new stages based on minimum and maximum stage per Var1-value
    DT[, .( V1 = paste0( "S ", min(stage):(max(stage)-1) ),
            V2 = paste0( "S ", (min(stage)+1):max(stage) ) ), by = .(Var1)][]

**output**

    #                  Var1  V1  V2
    # 1: 0060a00000fUbAnAAK S 2 S 3
    # 2: 0060a00000fUbAnAAK S 3 S 4
    # 3: 0060a00000fUbAnAAK S 4 S 5
```

Comment: update alse handles decreasing stages as provided in `example 2` of the question